# Filter a search of a database table in MySQL+PHP to get per search the closest result

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, xampp

Here are my code pieces, which are returning all the records, while I wish to only return the closest matches

```
  if (isset($_POST['name_query'])){                       
      if(preg_match("/^[ 0-99 a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name_query'])) 
            $sql="SELECT  client_id, id_num, name, surname FROM clients WHERE   name LIKE '%" . $name_query."%' " ; 

  else if(isset($_POST['surname_query'])){
      if(preg_match("/^[ 0-99 a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['surname_query'])){ 
            $sql="SELECT  client_id, id_num, name, surname FROM clients WHERE   surname LIKE '%" . $surname_query."%' " ; 

  elseif (isset($_POST['id_query'])){
      if(preg_match("/^[ 0-99 ]+/", $_POST['id_query'])){ 
            $sql="SELECT  client_id, id_num, name, surname FROM clients WHERE   client_id LIKE '%" . $id_query."%' " ;
```

Comment: You just need to decide what "a closer match" means, and then use that as a `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query *like* this - I use it in our Joomla-Page for a custom search. In this query I used "searchword" as the word we're searching for.

CEIL((LENGTH(title)-LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(title),LOWER('searchword'),'')))/LENGTH('searchword')*10+(LENGTH(introtext)-LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(introtext),LOWER('searchword'),'')))/LENGTH('searchword')*1) AS points